# Get instances from cluster

Tags: java, weka

How can I get the instances from the cluster by weka and java code?

this is my code:
I want to get cl instances .. How is this done?

```
 public Clustering(String filename) throws Exception {
        ClusterEvaluation eval;
        Instances data;
        String[] options;
        DensityBasedClusterer cl;    

        data = new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)));

        // normal
        System.out.println("\n--> normal");
        options    = new String[2];
        options[0] = "-t";
        options[1] = filename;
        System.out.println(ClusterEvaluation.evaluateClusterer(new EM(), options));

        // manual call
        System.out.println("\n--> manual");
        cl   = new EM();
        cl.buildClusterer(data);
    }
```

filename = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/file.arff"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `clusterInstance(Instance)` method to get the cluster number to which an instance has been assigned. The total number of clusters can be obtained by the `numberOfClusters()` method.